# Getting customer telephone & order_id on success page for Send SMS on opencart-2.0.3.1

Tags: sms, e-commerce, opencart2.x

How do I get customer telephone & order_id on the catalog/controller/checkout/success.php page for Send SMS on opencart-2.0.3.1?

I tried this:

```
//after this this line: $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('order_guest', $activity_data);} 
$orderID = $this->session->data['order_id'];
$msisdn=$this->customer->getTelephone();
$sms ='Congrats! You have successfully made orderID# '.$orderID.' Thank You. @TestSMS';
```

Showing Error as Follows:

- Warning: Illegal string offset 'breadcrumbs'
- Notice: Array to string conversion
- Warning: Illegal string offset 'breadcrumbs'

Comment: It seems that there are errors in the template file too `Illegal string offset 'breadcrumbs'`, please provide further information (the name of the file edited, the template being used ...)

Comment: I use fresh install default theme,I already mention success.php

Comment: SMS send successfully to customer mobile  with orderID

Comment: please post your your full file code here.

Comment: *first*: you should put the code before this line `$this->cart->clear();`, *second*: these changes have nothing to do with `$data['breadcrumbs']`, are you using vqmod extensions?

Comment: I download latest version just install , not install any module even not login admin panel yet

Comment: @NipunTyagi  file url as https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq7ekp2g294f26t/success.php?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for share your file code here.

You have used a variable `$data` before your curl requeset, as opencart has global variable $data itself in which all data move from controller to template.

```
$data=$param.$sms.$sid; 

$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); 
$response = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
```

Please change the $data variable name with any another variable here & userd the new variable in curl request, or used below code instaed of upper one

```
$dataNew=$param.$sms.$sid; 

$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$dataNew); 
$response = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
```

Comment: ! Great Work Now Without Error